# What is the expected structure of a csv file to feed in Pandas

Tags: pandas, csv

A project reads a list of images named `input_images.csv` like

```
images_paths = pd.read_csv('input_images.csv', index_col=0, header=None)[0]
```

I don't have the `input_images.csv`, but it should read `1.jpg, 2.jpg, ...` from  current folder. What should be the format of a csv file? Currently `input_images.csv` contains

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
...
```

But I get

```
--> 75 images_paths = pd.read_csv('input_images.csv', index_col=0, header=None)[0] 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2900             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2901                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2902             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2903             if is_integer(indexer):
   2904                 indexer = [indexer]

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2889                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2890             except KeyError as err:
-> 2891                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2892 
   2893         if tolerance is not None:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
images_paths = pd.read_csv('input_images.csv', index_col=0, header=None)[0]
```

to

```
images_paths = pd.read_csv('input_images.csv', header=None)[0]
```